# How to implement a Progressbar for an GhostScript convert

Tags: c#, progress-bar, ghostscript

Hi i'm using the GhostScriptDLL to convert PDF-Files to gray PNG images, 
this takes some time even if such a PDF-Files contain more than 1 Pages.

So i decided to implement a Progressbar into my app to show the user how far the converting is going?

But here the trouble starts i don't know how many Pages are in the PDF-File and i also don't know which Page does GhostScript currently converting

So is there a way to do this maybe i miss something but i wasn't able to find something usefull?

This is the [GhostScriptWrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API) i currently using.

Comment: You should be able to use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/) to count the number of pages and other objects in PDF files, that may help.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips so i should use iTextSharp instead of GhostScriptDLL? Ok i will give it a try if this will be the only way

Comment: I'm not sure, I've only dipped into PDF processing once or twice and just knew it could be used to get more info about your PDF.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips iTextSharp isn't anymore free for commercial use and the older versions contains some copyright issues so i don't thing this will be my first choice :(